# why do I get object doesn't support this property or method?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

for some reason

```
MsgBox (VarType(Application.WorksheetFunction.Address(1, getRowOfTestCode, 4, 1)))
```

where  `getRowOfTestCode = 13`

throws the

> error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method"

What am I missing here?

Comment: Not all worksheet functions are available for use in VBA.  You could use `Cells(r, c).Address()` instead

Comment: But the Vartype of an address will always be a string.  If you want the type of the value in the cell use the `.Value` not the `.Address`

Answer (score 3):

`Address` is not available in VBA via `WorksheetFunction`

You can instead use something like

```
Cells(rowNum, colNum).Address(False, False)
```

It's not clear from that one line what the context is for this though, so some other approach might be more useful.

Comment: Ah sorry! the result should be "N" but yes this works! thank you so much :)